# HTML Canvas updates stroke color for everything that's already been drawn

Tags: javascript, canvas, coffeescript

I have an interface with a color picker that allows the user to change the stroke color, but What's happening is, I start to draw - it draws black. I change the stroke to red, I draw - and everything that was black is now red. I have not the slightest clue as to why.

Here's the code I think is relevant. It's all within a coffeescript class

```
canvasMouseDown: (event) ->
  @offset = $(@canvas).offset()
  _x = @offset.left
  _y = @offset.top
  @ctx.moveTo event.pageX - _x, event.pageY - _y

  # does nothing more than save the current canvas via getImageData() to allow an undo
  @saveUndoState()

  @ctx.strokeStyle = @attr.stroke

  @canvas.bind "mousemove.canvasDraw", (e) =>
    x = e.pageX - _x
    y = e.pageY - _y

    @ctx.lineTo x, y
    @ctx.stroke()

initCanvas: ->
  @ctx = @canvas[0].getContext '2d'

  $(@canvas).bind "mousedown.canvasDraw", (e) =>
    @canvasMouseDown e
  $(@canvas).bind "mouseup.canvasDraw", (e) =>
    @canvasMouseUp e
```

Comment: It sounds like the script is keeping track of all 2d points used for calls to lineTo. Once the colour is changed, the next time the polyline is drawn it's draw using the current colour, which is now red instead of black. I'd (a) look for a place in which the coords get saved (b) look for a way to save a colour with those points.

Answer (score 0):

Blah. Forgot to include ctx.beginPath on the mousedown, and ctx.closePath at the mouseup